# Android autocomplete textview population using local json

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview, populate

How To use a local JSON(present in raw folder) file to populate an autocomplete textview?
I am new to android, and building a small application. plz help

Comment: First you need to parse the JSON into an array of Strings. Then you use that array for the autocomplete.

Comment: Please show some code so we can get an idea of what you have tried. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually documented information on this, it is called: [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Used like so:

```
    public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
}
```

You would then need to parse your JSON into the string[]... There are a couple good JSON parsing tutorials here:

Simple:

- http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Good:

- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: I want to add a permanent search result in autocomplete text view in android. For ex:If i enter 'x' in the autocomplete and if it shows the list of hotels...xyz1,xyz2.etc...Then the last result must be "NOT IN LIST" value. If the user cant find their hotel then they can select NOT IN LIST option..

Even if the user types in the text that the predictive search could not give then 'NOT IN LIST' should be the only suggestion that autocomplete should give.If i have to use custom autocomplete text view then what method should i override? If so ,tell me with a method code that i have to override